# List Items postion click on each row issue in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list of items in Listview.
In each row, I have **Text and image**. Currently, **the click effect is there for the entire row**. I want to add a specific click effect to text view and image.

How to do that?

Comment: Could you please share your code so we can help you?

Comment: I just added in my Xml like: <TextView  android:id android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />      <ImageView   android:id=""  android:layout_width="" android:layout_height="" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

Comment: We need to see the code of your list and its adapter and possibly a listener for the clicks. That is the layout of the rows but it has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a custom adapter for your listview... so if you override the getView method, there you can set the onclick listener for each of your views.

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
     public void onClick()
     { 
         // Do something
     } 
});
```

and

```
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
         public void onClick()
         { 
             // Do something
         } 
    });
```

Now, Doyou want the same listener defined in onItemClickListener in each of your views? easy: you can define your performance in another method, and only call it where you want.

I hope this help

Comment: My problem is only click effect.I am able to click on entire row in List view.But the problem is i have Text item and bookmark image in Each row.So i want to click only on Text or Image .Not entire row of ListView.